# How to get IE history using C++

Tags: c++, windows, internet-explorer

I'm looking for a way to get browsing history from Internet Explorer using c++ code, other browsers uses databases, but how about IE?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use COM interface called [IUrlHistoryStg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767721%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

---

Poor quality, but this is simple example how to enumerate IE history correctly.

```
int main()
{
    CoInitialize(NULL);

    IUrlHistoryStg* ieHistory = NULL;
    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CUrlHistory, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_IUrlHistoryStg, (LPVOID *)(&ieHistory));

    if (!SUCCEEDED(hr))
        return 1;

    IEnumSTATURL* urlEnumer;
    hr = ieHistory->EnumUrls(&urlEnumer);

    if (!SUCCEEDED(hr))
        return 2;

    if (!SUCCEEDED(urlEnumer->SetFilter(L"", STATURL_QUERYFLAG_ISCACHED|STATURL_QUERYFLAG_TOPLEVEL|STATURL_QUERYFLAG_NOURL|STATURL_QUERYFLAG_NOTITLE|STATURLFLAG_ISTOPLEVEL|STATURLFLAG_ISCACHED)))
        return 4;

    if (!SUCCEEDED(urlEnumer->Reset()))
        return 3;

    unsigned long correct = 0;
    STATURL result = {};

    struct Urls
    {
        std::wstring url;
        std::wstring title;

        Urls(LPWSTR url, LPWSTR title) : url(url ? url : L""), title(title ? title : L"")
        {}
    };

    std::vector<Urls> urls;

    do
    {
        result.cbSize = sizeof(result);
        if (SUCCEEDED(urlEnumer->Next(1, &result, &correct)))
        {
            Urls url(result.pwcsUrl, result.pwcsTitle);
            urls.push_back(url);
        }
    } 
    while (correct == 1);

    size_t size = urls.size();
    ieHistory->Release();
    urlEnumer->Release();

    return 0;
}
```

Before using this, please read documentation and add more appropriate error handling.

---

Also [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/338268/COM-in-C) read about COM.